# ウィザード方式の新規会員登録で情報がdbに保存されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

#### 前提・実現したいこと

ウィザード方式の新規会員登録でユーザー情報をdbに登録したいです。

現在、個人開発アプリを作成しております。
deviceを使ってウィザード方式フォームでユーザー登録を実現しようとしております。
１ページ目：プロフィール画像や名前など
２ページ目：住所（住所自動入力含む
３ページ目：完了ページ

他のモデルを作成する前までは、問題なく登録できていたのですが、
他のモデルの作成・アソシエーション実装後、dbに保存がされなくなってしまいました。
（他にもcarrierwaveのインストールなどもしているので、どこを境にできなくなったのかが明確ではありません。）

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

エラー文は特に出ていなかったので、saveからsave!に変更したところ、以下のようなエラー文が表示されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
また、コンソールは以下のようにROLLBACKとなってしまっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 該当のソースコード

【registrations_Controller.rb】
ウィザード方式のフォームに対応するdeviceのコントローラです。

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]


  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
    unless @user.valid?
      flash.now[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages
      render :new and return
    end
    session["devise.regist_data"] = {user: @user.attributes}
    session["devise.regist_data"][:user]["password"] = params[:user][:password]
    @address = @user.build_address
    render :new_address
  end
  
  def create_address
    @user = User.new(session["devise.regist_data"]["user"])
    @address = Address.new(address_params)

    unless @address.valid?
      flash.now[:alert] = @address.errors.full_messages
      render :new_address and return
    end
    @user.build_address(@address.attributes)
    @user.save!
    session["devise.regist_data"]["user"].clear
    sign_in(:user, @user)
  end
  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
  protected

  def address_params
    params.require(:address).permit(:zipcode, :prefecture_code, :city,:district, :building, :room)
  end
end
```

【Application_controller.rb】

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    posts_path
  end
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:nickname,:first_name,:last_name, :first_name_kana, :last_name_kana,:birthday,:image])
  end
end
```

【user.rb】

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  validates :nickname,:first_name,:last_name, :first_name_kana, :last_name_kana,:birthday,:image ,presence: true
  has_one :address
  has_many :posts
  has_many :messages
  
  has_many :group_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :group_users, dependent: :destroy
  include JpPrefecture
  jp_prefecture :prefecture_code
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  def prefecture_name
    JpPrefecture::Prefecture.find(code: prefecture_code).try(:name)
  end

  def prefecture_name=(prefecture_name)
    self.prefecture_code = JpPrefecture::Prefecture.find(name: prefecture_name).code
  end

end
```

【address.rb】

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  validates :zipcode, :prefecture_code, :city,:district,presence: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

#### 試したこと

■モデル
・アソシエーションが正しくできていない?

userモデルに関連してくる他のモデルはaddress,post,group,messageです。
それぞれにhas_many(one)とbelong toの関係がしっかり記述されているか確認した

・外部キーのnilを許可できていない?
belong_toの記述の後に, optional: trueを追記した

・画像が正しく２ページ目（住所登録）に引き継がれていない?
正しいかわからないですが、mount_uploader :image, ImageUploaderをaddress.rbにも追記

■コントローラ
・「Validation failed: Image can't be blank」のためimageが保存できていない？
application_controllerのdevise_parameter_sanitizerにimageが記載されているか確認

・@address = Address.new(address_params)の下に@address.user = current_userを追記
他で質問されていたもので、回答になっていたので、こちらも試してみました。

初めて、stack overflowを利用させていただきます。
質問の仕方がわかりにくいなどございましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
何卒宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/284029

Answer (score 0):

`image` でエラーになっているので、 carrierwave でアップロードされて、まだ save されていない画像が session 経由でちゃんと引き継がれていないようにみえます。

carrierwave で HTTP リクエストをまたいで保存されていない画像を扱うには `image` だけではなく `image_cache` も必要なので、 `@user.image_cache` も `session` に保存する必要があるのではないでしょうか? (validation error で hidden に `image_cache` が設定される使い方しかしたことがなくて、すぐに確認できる環境もなかったので、取り出し方は `@user.image_cache` ではないかもしれません。)

エラーとは直接は関係ないですが、 `regist_data` は `register_data` の方が良さそうです。
https://labs.cybozu.co.jp/blog/akky/2005/07/regist/

Comment: ありがとうございます！image_cacheはいまだにバリデーションに失敗したときに保持するものですね、、！こちらやってみたのですが、いまだに解決せず、、「regist_data」に関して、ありがとうございます！non-native特有の言葉として使われてしまっているのですね。こちら修正いたします！